# ¿Cómo hacer para que en Javascript no se repitan infinitamente los datos introducidos a través de los inputs en el DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, function, submit, form-submit

En este código de Javascript existe un pequeño formulario donde todo funciona bien pero el problema es que cuando el usuario se registra y el mismo usuario por error sigue pulsando el botón de "enviar" sigue apareciendo el mensaje infinitamente en el DOM.

¿Cómo podría hacer para que esto no suceda?

```
let registro= document.getElementById("registro");

registro.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    let nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value
    console.log("Has quedado registrado como "+nombre);

    let gracias= document.getElementById("gracias")

    let div= document.createElement("p");

    div.innerHTML="<p>!Gracias por registrarse en la página¡</p>";
    gracias.append(div);

})







<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../estilos/estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="navbar">
            <img src="../media/logo.PNG" class="logo" alt="Main Logo">
        

            <ul>
                <li><a href="../index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="./cotizador.html">Cotizador</a></li>
                <li><a href="./nosotros.html">Nosotros</a></li>
                <li><a href="./registro.html">Registrarse</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </header>

    <hr>

    <main>
        <form id="registro" action="" method="post">
            <h2>Registro</h2>
            <input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese su Nombre">
            <input type="text" name="edad" placeholder="Ingrese su Edad">
            <input type="text" name="correo" placeholder="Ingrese su Correo">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
          </form>

          <div id="gracias"></div>
    </main>

    


    <script src="../js/contacto.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si al hacer click ya obtuviste los datos haz un reload de ella al tener los datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hay nada malo en tu codigo, lo que está mas el es tu requerimiento, si no quieres que le de mas oculta en botton de enviar

```
 var btn= document.getElementById('id_de_mi_botton');
            btn.style.display = 'none';
```

Si lo que quieres es reiniciar todo, puedes hacer reload de la pagina

```
location.reload();
```

Tambien puedes ocultar el boton y despues recargar en x tiempo